Gradle Java include native library (Project Panama)
I've a rust library that I want to call from Java.
I've managed to create the corresponding .h-file and extract from that the Java bindings.
As long as my project structure looks like the following, I can access the c-function when compiling and starting the program with
javac --source=22 -d . src/my/panama/java/project/name/*.java
java --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED Main.java

├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── Main.java
├── my
│   └── panama
│       └── java
│           └── project
│               └── name
│                   ├── projectPanamaFiles.class
├── libmy_rust.dylib
├── my_rust_lib.h
└── src
    ├── my
    │   └── panama
    │       └── java
    │           └── project
    │               └── name
    │                   ├── projectPanamaFiles.java
    ├── lib.rs
    └── custom_functions.rs

Now I want to integrate the native library to my main project (Micronaut 4.4.2 & Java 22) with a structure looking like:
── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── my
        │       └── panama
        │           └── java
        │               └── project
        │                   └── name
        │                       └── Application.java
        └── rust
            ├── same As above

When I place all of the .class files of the Panama binding in src/main/java/my/Panama/java/project/name/library, I can use them in IntelliJ as every other library.
When I try to run my app, it fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot open library: libprocess_dlms.dylib.
I've tried adding it via gradle.kts via implementation(fileTree("src/main/rust")) but nothing changed.
Also adding it directly via System.load("/absolute/path/to/libmy_rust.dylib"); results in the same error message.
Where do I specify the wrong path? Does the file need to be at a specific place?
Is there a way of getting the compiler to output where it would've looked for the file?

The library loading is handled by the OS. For mac, the directory containing the libprocess_dlms.dylib file should be added to the list of paths in the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. See also the section on library loading in the jextract guide: https://github.com/openjdk/jextract/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#library-loading

I am able to run the program as long as the native library is in the same directory as my main class.
Whenever I move the library, it fails with Cannot open library: libprocess_dlms.dylib. It doesn't change anything if I pass the path via -Djava.library.path or if I put the library in a path specified in the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Loading it via System.load("/absolute/Path") doesn't throw an error directly but also changes nothing

How the native library is loaded depends on which SymbolLookup variant you used, respectively which jextract library option you chose:



SymbolLookup method
jextract option
Behavior




libraryLookup  (String name, ...)
--library <name>(this additionally performs a System.mapLibraryName(name) converting the name to the OS-specific library name, e.g. on Linux foo to libfoo.so)--library :<path>
The library is looked up in an OS-specific way.For example on Linux it is looked up in the path specified by LD_LIBRARY_PATH.


libraryLookup  (Path path, ...)
none(even the :<path> syntax uses libraryLookup(String name, ...) currently)
The library is loaded from the specified relative or absolute file.


loaderLookup()
no library option specifiedor--use-system-load-library--library <name>--use-system-load-library(this additionally calls System.loadLibrary(name))--library :<path>--use-system-load-library(this additionally calls System.load(file))
The library is looked up from all libraries which have been loaded with System.load(file) or System.loadLibrary(name) for the caller's class loader.



Note that the java.library.path System property affects only System.loadLibrary(name) (respectively Runtime.loadLibrary(name)), all other forms of loading libraries are unaffected by it (see JDK-8339367).
So where the native library is loaded from highly depends on which jextract option you used, and possibly also which OS you are using. You can see the relevant jextract generated code by looking for the SymbolLookup SYMBOL_LOOKUP constant in the generated ..._h.java class.
As mentioned in the jextract documentation, the Hotspot JVM option -Xlog:library can be used to get debug information at runtime about which native libraries are loaded.

I didn't manage to pass the path of the library to the JVM/Compiler in any kind.
Passing it via -Djava.library.path=/absolute/path/to/folder didn't work as well as loading it via System.load(absolutePath) or System.loadLibrary(libraryName).
But if the native library is placed at the project root where build.gradle.kts is, it picks it up automatically.
Seems like it is somewhere predefined, that the library that is going to be loaded has to be at the project root/the "starting point" of where you execute your application (execute the command to start).
I'll now accept my own answer, but if anybody knows how to define a different location for the native library, I'll be happy accepting that.
